# HTML CSS text like a sidebar next to an image

Tags: html, css, image, styles, sidebar

I have a problem at my Website.
I want to "print" text on the left of an image. But I dont know how to do this.
Here my Site: [link](http://martin-fischer.tk/)
Here how it should look: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ2Qr.png)

[image]

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please post a complete code example *in your question*.

Comment: Oh im using jadejs and stylus, can't you rightclick and view code? btw I have no code cause I dont know how to do this

Comment: you can make a CSS file for print..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `img` tag with:

```
<img src="http://martin-fischer.tk/assets/img/AVRStick.png" style="float: left;">
<p>Here the text</p>
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/gU7Xp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** As per the attached image to align the text with image you could use `float:left`. And your layout won't broke so you have to clear the `float` either using `clearfix Method` or you can use `overflow:hidden` on parent div. In addition to be safer side you could `display:inline-block`.

By Using `@media` query  you can create a stylesheet for `screen`, `mobile` and even you can control the elements while printing the document. Have a Look at the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xuwizoda/1/edit)**.

In this example in print preview you can see the changes. Elements position is change for print and the font will turn red.

```
@media screen {
    p {
        font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      float:left;
    }
  img{float:left;}
}

@media print {
    p {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
       float:right;
    }
  img{float:right;}
}
```

Comment: He didn't wanted the text to come when user prints a page. He wanted the text to come beside the USB.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui what does it means then `I want to "print" text on the left of an image.`

Comment: Your explanation is wrong , not what i asked but with float left it works ^^

Comment: He meant he wanted to place text on the left of the image

Comment: @user3859452 Is my answer what you wanted?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui how is your answer different.

Comment: @KheemaPandey it's alot different, check it out.

Comment: @user3859452 Now I've updated my answer with more explanations. Now it would be more helpful for you and future visitors. you may accept my answer now.